# How to intentionally corrupt my file system or crash its driver?

Tags: linux, filesystems, testing

I am doing a research that involves **intentionally** corrupting my file system. I shouldn't be able to read or write anything to the file system after that. Therefore I am ok with crashing the drivers to the filesystem instead of corrupting the file system. Also, I am ok with my kernel freezing with it. Is there a set of operations, a standard way or a specific program that I can use to achieve this? It would be great if I can replicate the method in a non Linux environment as well (in GNU Hurd). Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean for a filesystem to crash? Processes crash, systems crash, ... basically things that are running crash. Except maybe for ZFS and XFS, there usually aren't processes running for a filesystem. If you want to corrupt a filesystem, you can write to the underlying block device directly.

Comment: If you can find a stress test that leads to data corruption, the filesystem would be very buggy and it would be a major reason for concern. So I doubt "I understand that running a stress test for an extended amount of time may crash the file system" really comes from solid *understanding*. It's really not clear what you mean, but you do have quite a few misconceptions. Can you put into clear words what you intend "crashing a file system" to do?

Comment: Just overwrite the first megabyte of your blockdevice with zeros or something, good luck recovering that.

Comment: Maybe all you need is a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)?

Comment: I want the file system process to stop working and halt in a way so that it doesn't restart automatically. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Unplug the system drive?

Comment: As you've already been told, the file system is not a "process" and it's not something that's "running", thus it cannot be "halted". A file system is represents a data that exists on a disk. Please google what a "file system" is. Also, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. We can give you a way to overwrite the disk and corrupt it, but it will not be able to recover later.

Comment: Check [fsfreeze](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fsfreeze.8.html) if you want to (temporarily) suspend all writes to a filesystem.

Comment: In a microkernel, there is a file system server that manages the operations of a file system, so I assumed Linux has a similar parent process that controls its operations. But if that is not the case, then what I'm looking for is a way to corrupt the entire file system.

Comment: A non-microkernel OS also usually has a particular module to deal with the filesystem, just perhaps not as a separate process. But while the filesystem driver is code (and likely keeps some state you could mess with), the filesystem itself is just a data structure. Now, depending on what you want, you could mess with the filesystem on disk behind the OS filesystem driver's back, and if you happened to violate some assumptions it made, you might get the OS to crash.

Comment: Or, if you wanted to be more direct about it, you could corrupt the in-memory data structures of the filesystem driver, or the code itself, either of which should make it pretty easy to get it to crash.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. I will update the question to ask about crashing the file system. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this in linux?

Comment: simulating failing devices for testing purposes - [dm-flakey](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/device-mapper/dm-flakey.html)

Answer (score 1):

Corrupting the filesystem is super easy, just write random data to the partition start and the filesystem will be damaged.

Examples: I will assume the partition is `/dev/sda1`

- Write a random 4KiB block of data to the partition:
  `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1 bs=4096 count=1`
- Completely destroy the filesystem and its data: `sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda1`

You can also echo some plaintext and use output redirection to write to the partition start, this would corrupt the filesystem metadata.